# How to access datetime from HTML <time> element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, datetime, time

```
<h4>here is time<time datetime="2018-11-18">18.11.2018</time>!</h4>
```

Probably, it is simple, but how do I get the date from datetime in the time element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure JS:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].getAttribute('datetime');
```

in jQuery:

```
console.log($('time:first').attr('datetime'));
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].getAttribute('datetime'));
console.log($('time:first').attr('datetime'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>here is time<time datetime="2018-11-18">18.11.2018</time>!</h4>
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it for me. The :first attribute was missing. Can you also tell me, why the :first attribute is required? I tried `$('time')[0].attr('datetime')´ and got 'e.attr is not a function' before...

Comment: `$('time')[0]` is a JS element so use of jQuery attr will not work. :first (http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) will you the first occurrence from multiple elements